# How to map an array of arrays into an array of objects with a given keys array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

From an **array of keys** and an **array of arrays**, like this:

```
const keys = ['foo', 'bar'];
const vals = [
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B']
];
```

How to get an **array of objects** like below ?

```
[
  {'foo' : 'a', 'bar' : 'A'},
  {'foo' : 'b', 'bar' : 'B'}
]
```

Maybe using `lodash` ?

Comment: Can you share the code which you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loash's [`_.zipObject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObject) to create an object from an array of keys and values for each value array inside your 2d array using the [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) method:

```js
const keys = ['foo', 'bar']
const vals = [
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B']
];

const res = _.map(vals, arr => _.zipObject(keys, arr));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you prefer vanilla JS, then you could use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on a zipped array (created using `.map()`):

```js
const keys = ['foo', 'bar']
const vals = [
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B']
];

const res = vals.map(
  arr => Object.fromEntries(arr.map((v, i) => [keys[i], v]))
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more generic, you can use `Array.reduce()` with `index` variable

```js
const keys = ['foo', 'bar']
const values = [
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B']
]

const mapped = values.map(val => val.reduce((acc, cur, i) => ({...acc, [keys[i]]: cur}),{}))

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: Using ```map``` is incorrect, can anybody say why using map is incorrect?

Comment: Why do you think using `map` is incorrect? OP's trying to **map** items of the array to some values.

Comment: ```map``` will return elements lengths equal to main array, but final result length, may not equal to initial length.

Comment: No. The outer array has 2 items (sub-arrays) and the final array also has 2 items (objects) . If the outer array would have `n` items, the final array would also have `n` items as well

Comment: Yes, but only here.

Answer (score 1):

With lodash/fp you can generate a function using `_.flow()`, that curries `_.zipObject()` with the `keys`, and the `_.map()` with the curried `_.zipObject()`, and then you can call it with `vals` to get the array of objects:

```js
const fn = _.flow(_.zipObject, _.map);

const keys = ['foo', 'bar']
const vals = [
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B']
];

const result = fn(keys)(vals);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using `reduce`.

```js
let keys = ['foo', 'bar'];

let values = [
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B']
];

const res = values.reduce((a, [first, second]) => {
    return [...a, {[keys[0]]: first, [keys[1]]: second}];
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dataKeys = ['foo', 'bar'];
let dataValues = [
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B']
];

let transformed = dataValues.reduce((result,item)=>{
  result.push(
    dataKeys.reduce((r,dk,index)=>{
      let o = {};
      o[dk]= item[index];
      return {...r, ...o}
    },{})
  )
  return result
},[]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(transformed,null,2));
```