# Convert 2d array into object with unknown quantity of key and key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script, 2d

I learnt how to convert 2d array to object as below. However, this case we know exactly the quantity of key and key name (3 keys: name, price, place):

```
const myArray = [
  ['Rice', '$6', 'super market'],
  ['water', '$7', 'traditional market']
];

const myObj = myArray
  .map(([name, price, place]) => ({ name, price, place }));

console.log(myObj);
```

How can we have the same function with unknown qty of key and key name? for examble, myArray can be

```
const myArray = [
  ['Rice', '$6'],
  ['water', '$7']
];
```

or

```
const myArray = [
  ['Rice', '$6',"promotion"],
  ['water', '$7',"normal"]
];
```

or whatever, and I also have a array of corresponding key name like ['name','price','promotion'] for each type of array.

Thank you,

I tried to replace [name, price, place] of below to a defined variable of key name but it didn't work

```
const myObj = myArray
  .map(([name, price, place]) => ({ name, price, place }));
```

Comment: What do you mean *'it didn't work'*? The last example will work fine it just assigns `undefined` to `place`. You'll need to provide more clarity for concrete answers. Or do you mean map the keys from a separate array?

Comment: duplicate: [How to map an array of arrays into an array of objects with a given keys array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592723/how-to-map-an-array-of-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects-with-a-given-keys-array)

Comment: Oh thank you Pilchard, I found the answer in your link using Object.fromEntries()

Answer (score 0):

[Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) expects an array that contains key-value pairs, which is not what you have currently. You can use it if you `Array.map()` each row in the 2D array into key-value pairs. Alternatively, use `Array.forEach()`. Here's a demonstration of the two approaches:

```js
function test() {
  const keys = ['name', 'price', 'promotion',];
  const array2d = [
    ['Rice', '$6', 'super market'],
    ['water', '$7', 'traditional market'],
  ];
  console.log(arraysToObjects1_(keys, array2d));
  console.log(arraysToObjects2_(keys, array2d));
}

function arraysToObjects1_(keys, array2d) {
  return array2d.map(row => Object.fromEntries(row.map((value, index) => [keys[index], value])));
}

function arraysToObjects2_(keys, array2d) {
  const result = [];
  array2d.forEach(row => {
    const obj = {};
    keys.forEach((key, index) => obj[key] = row[index]);
    result.push(obj);
  });
  return result;
}
```