# Is there a more compact way to declare an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm a C# developer who uses JavaScript when I need to.

Is there a more compact way to write the following? Is it necessary to repeat the name of every member for each item?

```js
let cars = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "type": "minivan",
    "registration": new Date('2017-01-03'),
    "capacity": 7
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": "station wagon",
    "registration": new Date('2018-03-03'),
    "capacity": 5
  },
  {
    ...
  },
]
```

Comment: use a loop and just pass a 2D array of values?

Comment: You can write a function that does this

Comment: @XMehdi01: Adding a new function makes it more compact?

Comment: possible dupe: [How to map an array of arrays into an array of objects with a given keys array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592723/how-to-map-an-array-of-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects-with-a-given-keys-array)

Comment: @pilchard: I don't have keys. I'm just trying to declare the data structures described.

Comment: Your question is literally *'do I have to type the name of every property'* these names are often referred to as 'keys', so yes you do have keys.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question with an example of the C# code you might use. Then we'd be more able to see what you mean by _compact_ in order to provide a JS equivalent

Comment: You have shown no effort to solve this yourself using general programming structures (loops aren't javascript specific), nor have you described what you mean by compact, or how C# would allow what you are asking for.

Comment: "compact" is open to a wide variety of interpretation.

Comment: @pilchard: Given that javascript is not compiled, more compact would literally mean less characters in the source code. A loop is not an option. I just need to declare the data structures. There is nothing to loop until the data structures are defined.

Comment: Fine, then minify it. That's more compact. **BOOM**

Comment: @devlincarnate amusingly, minifying wouldn't do much for this given keys and values cannot be changed

Comment: Not sure why this has reopen votes given that the OP has added no further context since it was closed for focus. Where is this array being defined? Is the data being read in from a file or simply typed in? If it is just duplication the OP is trying to avoid some version of the [flagged dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592723/how-to-map-an-array-of-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects-with-a-given-keys-array) or the single answer already provided is more than ample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you using a factory function:

```js
function createCar(color, type, registration, capacity) {
  return {
    color,
    type,
    registration: new Date(registration),
    capacity,
  };
}
let cars = [
  createCar("purple", "minivan", "2017-01-03", 7),
  createCar("red", "station wagon", "2018-03-03", 5),
];
```

Comment: This would work, but I'm not sure I would characterize it as more compact.

Comment: @JonathanWood I disagree with the answers repeated function calls, but it is categorically more compact.